# NetSuite SuiteScript 1.0 - Run Search and Email Results as CSV

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to update an existing script to include sending the results in an email as an attached csv file.  I get nothing when I run the script - no error and no email.  I am new to scripting and have tried numerous examples found online with no results.

Here is the code that I have tried with the email piece added at the bottom from an older post that I found:

function SaveSearchesAllCo() {

```
//Run and Save Calendared Event Data for Month 1
    d = new Date();
    y = d.getFullYear();
    m = d.getMonth();
    day = new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();
    var days = new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();
    var today = new Date(y, m, day);

    var ContentArray1 = new Array();

    for (var k = 0; k < days; k++){
        today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1)

        var filterday1 = nlapiDateToString(today)

        var Search1 = nlapiLoadSearch('calendarevent', 'customsearch4835')

        var newfilters1 = new Array();
            newfilters1[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('date', null, 'on', filterday1,null)
            
        Search1.setFilters(newfilters1)
        var SearchResultsSet1 = Search1.runSearch()
        var Results1 = SearchResultsSet1.getResults(0, 1000)

        // Creating some array's that will be populated from the saved search results
        var content1 = new Array();
        var temp1 = new Array();
        var x = 0;

        // Looping through the search Results
        for (var i = 0; i < Results1.length; i++){
            var resultSet1 = Results1[i];

            // Returns an array of column internal Ids
            var columns1 = Search1.getColumns();
            
            // Looping through each column and assign it to the temp array
            for (var y = 0; y <= columns1.length; y++){
                temp1[y] = resultSet1.getValue(columns1[y]);
                //replace the 2nd date with the filterday
                temp1.splice(7,1,filterday1);
            }
            
            //move the first column value to become the 16th column value
            var os = temp1[0];
            temp1.splice(16, 0, os);
            temp1.shift();
                
            content1[x] = temp1.toString();
            x++
        }
        //Create new ContentArray as to keep the splice static per day
        for (i=0; i< content1.length; i++){
            ContentArray1.push(content1[i])
        }
    }

    // Creating a string variable that will be used as the CSV Content
    var data1 = "" ;

    // Looping through the content array and assigning it to the contents string variable.
    for (var z = 0; z < ContentArray1.length; z++) {
        data1 += ContentArray1[z] + '\n';
    }

    // Creating a csv file and passing the contents string variable. 
    var file1 = nlapiCreateFile('Calendared Event Data - All CO through ' + today.toISOString().slice(0,10) +'.csv', 'CSV', data1);
    file1.setFolder(16604)

    //Save File to the Cabinet for later retrieval
    nlapiSubmitFile(file1)
    
    //send email
    var fromid = 28940;
    var toemail = 'genericemail@gmail.com'; //changed for this purpose
    var sbj = 'test';
    var msg = 'test';
    var attach = [file1];
    
    
    nlapiSendEmail(fromid, toemail, sbj, msg, null, null, null, attach);
```

}

Comment: What's the question?  You have a desired behavior, and you have a script that broadly seems to do that; is something not working as expected?  Do you get an error when you run it?

Comment: I get nothing when I run it - no error, no file saved in the file cabinet, and no email

Comment: I'd suggest running it in the [SuiteScript debugger](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/97287) or adding debug logs to try to pinpoint where the issue is occurring.   Once you know what the error is or where it's occurring, the fix may be obvious, but if not let us know and we'll try to help!

Comment: Ran it through the debugger and it worked so that told me I was missing something in the deployment setup.  Thanks for the help and hopefully this will help someone else since I spent 2 days trying to get the right code.

Comment: Glad it worked for you now!  Please consider writing an answer of your own detailing what the issue was and how you fixed it, as that could help future inquirers.